# Bounded moments implies finite moments of supremum?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Suppose that, for all $(t,x) \in [0,T]\times \mathbb{R}$, a two-parameter stochastic process $Z(t,x)$ satisfies
$$
\| Z(t,x)\|_{L^p(\Omega)} \leq C_{p,T} 
$$
for some constant depending on $p$ and $T$. Is it necessarily true that the following holds? 
$$
\Big\| \sup_{(t,x) \in [0,T]\times \mathbb{R}} Z(t,x) \Big\|_{L^p(\Omega)} < \infty
$$

---

EDIT: I should mention that this process has some Holder regularity in both $t$ and $x$.

Comment: What kind of Hoelder regularity are you assuming?

Comment: 1/4 in $t$ and 1/2 in $x$

Comment: Without Hoelder continuity, it's not true - consider

$Z(t, x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty n 1_{\{(t,x) = (T_n, X_n)\}}$

where, say, $(T_n, X_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ are iid and absolutely continuous on $[0,T]\times\mathbb{R}$. To get a similar result with $Z$ Hoelder continuous almost surely, you should be able to replace the indicators with Hoelder continuous, compactly supported kernel functions and choose a suitable distribution for the $X_n$.